# Getting the set-cookie header from a web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, setcookie

How do I get the set-cookie header from a webpage?

I tried using below code:

```
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', document.location, false);
        req.send(null);
        var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
        alert(headers);
```

But this does not give the set-cookie header.

So how do I get it?( I actually can see the set-cookie value in browser's inspect element network tab).

If its not possible to get the set-cookie, then is there a way I could set something via server end that will allow me to get that value?

Comment: Could you explain why `document.cookie` is not sufficient for your needs? Do you need to check exactly when a cookie is set, and it's too much trouble to do that manually with repeated checks to `document.cookie`? Or is it an HTTPOnly cookie, not visible in `document.cookie`?

Comment: @apsillers yes document.cookie is not showing me that value. I am not sure what an HTTPOnly cookie is. Is it the same as set-cookie header?

Comment: also important to know if request is cross domain or not

Comment: @charlietfl no its not a cross domain request. Its not even ajax.

Comment: The [HttpOnly flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) on a cookie means that JavaScript is not allowed to read the cookie (i.e., it is only used for HTTP requests). Note also that [the exclusion of `set-cookie` is by design](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders%28%29-method): "*Return all response headers, excluding headers that are a case-insensitive match for Set-Cookie or Set-Cookie2...*" Perhaps the server could just replicate the value of the `set-cookie` header in a differently-named header? This is potentially a security violation, if HttpOnly applies.

Comment: @rahulserver `XMLHttpRequest` is ajax

Comment: @charlietfl yes I know. But my purpose is to get the set-only cookie in my current page header. That code was taken from somewhere else on SO. My ultimate purpose is to get the set-cookie value.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what your Set-Cookie header looks like?